# Understanding the proof showing that the Weyl group $W$ provides a full system of representatives for $B$\ $G/B$ when $G = SL_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, lie-groups

This is following Steinberg's "Lectures on Chevalley groups", PDF available online, page 28 example $a$.

I give a bit of context and then ask my question below. My actual question doesn't require knowledge of Bruhat decomposition and the other things mentiond in the next paragraph.

At this point the Bruhat decomposition has already been proven for any groups with a $(B,N)$ pair. The author gives a more direct proof that the Weyl group of $SL_n$, which is $S_n$, gives a complete system of representatives for the double cosets of $B$\ $G/B$  in the Bruhat decomposition $SL_n =\bigsqcup_{v \in W} BvB$.

$B$ is here the subgroup of upper triangular matrices, the cartan subgroup $H$ is the subgroup of diagonal matrices, and $S_n$ can be identified with monomial matrices.

I am going to type the proof here, and I'm going to bold the parts I would like clarification on. Thank you so much!!

---

Example $(a)$: **Move to $GL_n$ for convenience**. We will now prove that $W \cong S_n$ forms a complete system of representatives for $B$\ $G/B$. Given $x \in G$, choose $b \in B$ to maximize the total # of zero's at the beginning of all rows of $bx$. These beginnings must all be of different lengths, otherwise we could subtract a multiple of some row from an earlier one, i.e. **modify b, and increase the total # of zero's**. It follows that for some $w \in S_n$, $wbx$ is upper diagonal, whence $x \in Bw^{-1}B$. Now assume $BwB = Bw'B$ with $w,w' \in S_n$. Then $w^{-1}bw'$ is upper diagonal for some $b \in B$. Since $w,w'$ are permutation matices and **the matric positions where the identity is nonzero are included among those of b, we conclude that $w^{-1}w'$ is upperdiagonal, whence $w=w'$.

Comment: What is $B$ exactly? If $B$ consists of the upper **uni**triangular matrices, then $\bigsqcup_{v \in W} BvB$ is too small to be $SL_n$ at least for $n = 2$. If $B$ consists of all upper triangular matrices, then $\bigsqcup_{v \in W} BvB$ is too large to be $SL_n$.

Comment: Oh right, I'm sorry. It's the subgroup of $SL_n$ of all upper triangular matrices, that is to say, a maximal connected solvable subgroup.

Comment: But $W$ is not contained in $SL_n$ for $n \geq 2$, so how exactly should the Bruhat decomposition be interpreted?

Comment: I can't help with Steinberg's argument (which seems too short to be readable anyway), but the proof of the decomposition $GL_n = \bigsqcup\limits_{w \in S_n} BwB$ appears in the proof of Proposition 4.3.7 in [my notes *Hopf Algebras in Combinatorics* with Vic Reiner](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/HopfComb-sols.pdf). The proof should be self-contained except for notations (we use $\mathfrak{S}_n$ for the symmetric group $S_n$). Or so I believe (it's been a while).

Comment: cool, thanks man! edit: Holy crap lots of pages!!!

Comment: Oh, and this should include some alternative proofs: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15438/a-slick-proof-of-the-bruhat-decomposition-for-gl-nk